# xcode command line to upload screenshots, description and metadata to itunesconnect

Tags: xcode, command-line, continuous-deployment, fastlane

I know how to use xcodebuild, atool to build, archive and upload an ipa file to itunesconnect.

```
altool --upload-app -f "myapp.ipa" -u $USERNAME -p $PASSWORD
```

And there are some third party tools like fastlane that have function to upload screenshots, description, and metadata to itunesconnect.

However I don't want to use third party tools.

Is there any command line tool by Apple that can be used to upload screenshots, description and metadata to itunesconnect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as you really want to do this by tour self, but first I have to say, it's not like a "huge" third party library but ok:
Here is the documentation how you could achieve this: [App upload using macOS with -assetFile](https://help.apple.com/itc/transporteruserguide/#/apdA1391e560), you can find even more informations in this link.
I also recommend see last WWDC videos about: 1 [What's New in App Store Connect](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/301/) and 2 [Automating App Store Connect](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/303).

But, really try a look at the "Spaceship" action from fastlane, fastlane become a suit of tools, so, you don't need everything, just use the one that you need, like, "Spaceship", or, even better if you really want, look at the source code and get what you want, the beautiful of be open-source :D [Spaceship](https://spaceship.airforce/)